# how to modify Angular assets JSON file in webpack compile time

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I have this file named `config.json` on my assets folder in my Angular 9 project:

```
{ "a": 7 }
```

and I use this config in my project by import it dynamically at runtime using angular's `http.get("/assets/config.json")` and not by `import config "../assets/config.json"` so that i could change it at runtime and changes will apply to my application instantly with no need to recompile and build again.

My wish is to be able to modify this json at compile time using webpack, although I dont import it directly.

i tried to use [string-replace-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-webpack-plugin) but it doesn't take care of files which were not imported.

Really need some help here, thanks in advance.

Comment: If you need just create this file when compiling, try generate this file: https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-file-webpack

var opts = {
     path: './assets',
    fileName: 'config.json',
    content: '{ "a": 7 }'
};

Comment: Or you can create endpoint on your backend which will response needed config (generating  json object or mutating some config, etc.)

Comment: @dark_gf i dont need to create it. its already exist. I just need to modift its content at compile time, with different parameters each compilation (parmas I can give to a plugin via webpack.config.js, for example). backend is not an option for me. thia config file should be only present on client side.